# Pair t-test or Welch's t-test on a non-normal data series?

Tags: t-test, normality-assumption, paired-data

I have rainfall time series of 85 points from 1901-2013. I want to check whether the mean rainfall during 1901-1970 is significantly different than that of the mean rainfall during 1971-2013.

Here, the data would not 'necessarily' follow the normal distribution. So, one of the main assumption for applying t-test may not be fulfilled.

Now as the length of the dataset for two samples would be **70** and **43**, can I use the paired t-test or Welch's t-test assuming that the length is sufficient to circumvent the assumption of normality.

What should be the minimum length of data to overcome the normality condition in t-test, is 43 good enough?

In case, it's not then what test should be applied?

Comment: I doubt there's a good reason to think you'll have near-independence across time, so I wouldn't suggest either.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Mann-Whitney U test, which is quite robust and reasonably powerful. Otherwise you can first check for normality (eg with the Shapiro-Wilks test) and then use the t test if the hypothesis of normality is not rejected.